# Django, query to filter instead of iterating

Tags: django, django-queryset

So I have this database on auctions (WoW) and I update by tables once an hour. Simplified it looks like this:

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    auction_id = models.IntegerField()
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
    owner = models.CharField()
    buyout = models.IntegerField()
```

The data I get is in the form of a list of dictionaries looking like this:

```
new_auctions = [
    { 'auction_id' : <int>, 'item_id' : <int>, 
      'owner' : <string>  , 'buyout'  : <int>
    },
    # more auctions
]
```

Now I want to check if an auction has been relisted or not.
And now I want to see if:

- The auction is gone
- There is another auction by the same owner for the same item
- The price is less then the former auction

Then I will assume the auction was not sold but relisted.

My current solution started off by getting all the auctions that have dissapeared:

```
auction_ids = map(lambda d: d['auction_id'], new_auctions)
dead_auctions = Auction.objects.exclude(auction_id__in=auction_ids)
```

So now I thought I could iterate over every auction in dead_auctions and see if there's an auction in new_auctions by the same owner for the same item for a lower price.

I have this feeling that it's inelegant and possibly inefficient because

- Just finished a course in algorithms and *"It's O(n²), as bad as bubble sort!"*
- A friend told me *"you should never iterate over databases, only make queries"*.
- I'm not good enough at Django(/databases) yet to know if there's a smart query that could substitute this.

Comment: what''s an auction that's disappeared?

Comment: Ah, I think I will try to rewrite this question to make it more general, and not about my specific issue. An auction that has disappeared is an auction that I have in my database (meaning it was there when I looked the last time ~1h ago) but now is gone (in the new data) .

Comment: Do you load the new auctions into the database? if you don't you can't query your database for them!